# Remove ".php" file extension when using S3 / EC2

Tags: apache, .htaccess, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3

I have set up an application and uploaded the files using elastic beanstalk. The files are saved in a S3 bucket with a EC2 instance running.

The problem is I can only access the site files when manually adding the extension ".php".

I built the application using a .htaccess file for removing the file extension then my redirects and functions would use files without the ending e.g. "/index" instead of "/index.php".

Because .htaccess is not an option using S3 buckets is there an easy alternative way of removing file extensions ? ( so "/index.php" files are read as "/index" then all functions/redirects work fine ).

Answer (score 0):

You can use mod_rewrite to achieve this.
For example, this rule redirects to index when the file was not found in the current directory. For example, if you access /users, and since it´s not a file. The request will be foward to index.php. In index.php you can process the URL using $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI] and require the right file.

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```